# Проблема с выводом функции в указаном месте

Tags: php, функции

Здравствуйте! У меня есть класс, а в нем функция, в которой текст (выводится опператорм echo), я вывожу функцию из класса на странице, но текст выводиться не там, где надо, а на самом верху страницы, а с помощью return вообще ничего не выводит. Что делать? Сама функция вызывается вот так

```
$class = new main;
$page = $class->page_profile();
```

А $page выводиться опператором echo, но почему-то все выводит не так. Почему?

Comment: Показывайте код.

Answer (score 1):

```
return
```

Вы как вообще нормально, у вас везде стоит **return**, что ни проверка, так **return**.

return только в самый конец функции поставьте!

Дальше круче

```
while($messages = mysql_fetch_array($tmp));
    // нафига тут стоит while, который ни хрена не делает? Нет может он, конечно, и обрабатывает строки, но что он с ними делает-то? переписывайте код.
}
else {
    //если сообщений не найдено
    return "Сообщений нет";
}
```

А если сразу в лоб вам дать, то ошибка та, что у вас везде **RETURN** и толку от вашей функции никакого.

7 строчка

```
<title><?php return $myrow['login']; ?></title>
```

Вот до этого момента доходит интерпретатор и возвращает то, что должен, а именно

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
```

Что хотел, то и возвращает, правильно пишите код и будет вам счастье.

У меня все.

PPS Код - говнокод, извините, конечно, но это вы в первый раз писали функцию или честно стырили откуда-то?

```
function funct() {
    $number = 1234567;
    return $number; // вернет 1234567 RETURN используется только здесь, ну или если есть условия разного выхода из функции, то их может быть несколько.
}
```

Comment: Я сделал так. Я в функцию вписал echo "Привет"; оно вывело Привет в самом верху не там где надо а с ретурн ваще ничего не выводит. В чем подгвостка?

Comment: RETURN ты должен использовать только в самом конце, там где ты возвращаешь что-то из функции, до этого момента RETURN использовать НЕЛЬЗЯ НИ В КОЕМ СЛУЧАЕ!

В конце ответа посмотри кусок кода, и если что посмотри ответ @Sh4dow

Answer (score 1):

```
function page_profile () {
  ob_start(); // включаем буферизацию
  /* code, echo, print... NOT return*/
  $str = ob_get_contents(); // получаем буфер
  ob_end_clean(); // чистим буфер
  return $str; // возвращаем буфер)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, насколько я понял (включаем телепатию, так как тех трех строк маловато для того, чтобы составить картину кода) `$page = $class->page_profile();` - сделав это вы и выводите тот текст, ведь там в методе стоит echo(*"есть класс, а в нем функция в которой текст (выводится опператом echo)"*), а вы ожидаете, что вывод будет ниже, когда вы сделаете:  `echo $page;` если я прав, то у вас два решения или писать `$class->page_profile();` (или даже `main::page_profile()`, ну это уже смотрим сам код класса) на том месте, где `echo $page;` или изменить реализацию метода `page_profile()`, сделав там не `echo`, a `return`.

Comment: Вот ссылка на файл http://files.gw.kz/8eameykh5p.html
P.S. Код большой поэтому неразместил его сдесь